# Mapping Query Result with Entity Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Following code helps me to automatically map the query result with Entity properties. For example, result of the following query “ReportTypeCode“ is mapped with Report object’s ReportTypeCode property.

```
SELECT R.report_type_code AS ReportTypeCode FROM Report_Type R
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is there any datatype or scenario that it will not be able to handle?
2. Is there any improvement suggestions?

**CODE**

```
public static class EntityDataMappingHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Method for filling entity  from data
    /// </summary>
    public static void FillEntityFromRecord(Object entity, Dictionary<string, object> record)
    {
        if (entity != null && record != null)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] propertyInfoArray = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propertyInfoArray)
            {
                if (record.ContainsKey(prop.Name))
                {
                    if (String.Equals(prop.PropertyType.FullName, "System.String"))
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(entity, DBNull.Value.Equals(record[prop.Name]) ? null : Convert.ToString(record[prop.Name], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), null);
                    }
                    else if (String.Equals(prop.PropertyType.FullName, "System.Decimal"))
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(entity, DBNull.Value.Equals(record[prop.Name]) ? 0 : 
                            Convert.ToDecimal(record[prop.Name], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(entity, DBNull.Value.Equals(record[prop.Name]) ? null : record[prop.Name], null);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method for selecting records from Data Reader
    /// </summary>
    public static ArrayList SelectRecords(Collection<Object> entityList, IDataReader reader)
    {
        ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList();
        if (entityList != null && reader != null)
        {
            List<string> propertiesOfAllEntities = new List<string>();
            foreach (Object entity in entityList)
            {
                PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo = entity.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo prop in propertyInfo)
                {
                    propertiesOfAllEntities.Add(prop.Name);
                }
            }
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> record = MapPropertiesToReaderValues(propertiesOfAllEntities, reader);
                resultList.Add(record);
            }
        }
        return resultList;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper method for mapping properties with reader values
    /// </summary>
    private static Dictionary<string, object> MapPropertiesToReaderValues(List<string> propertiesOfAllEntities, IDataReader reader)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> propertyResultList = new Dictionary<string, object>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            string readerFieldName = reader.GetName(i);
            //Whether propertiesOfAllEntities.Contains the property
            if (propertiesOfAllEntities.FindIndex(x => x.Equals(readerFieldName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) != -1)
            {
                propertyResultList.Add(readerFieldName, reader[i]);
            }

        }
        return propertyResultList;
    }

}
```

**Client to Test**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    Collection<Report> reports = new Collection<Report>();
    string connectionString = "Data Source=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string commandText = @"SELECT R.report_type_code AS ReportTypeCode 
                                    FROM Report_Type R";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    Collection<Object> entityList = new Collection<Object>();
                    entityList.Add(new Report());
                    ArrayList records = EntityDataMappingHelper.SelectRecords(entityList, reader);
                    for (int i = 0; i < records.Count; i++)
                    {
                        Report report = new Report();
                        Dictionary<string, object> currentRecord = (Dictionary<string, object>)records[i];
                        EntityDataMappingHelper.FillEntityFromRecord(report, currentRecord);
                        reports.Add(report);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**DTO/Entity**

```
public class Report
{
    public Int16? ReportTypeCode { get; set; }
    public string ReportName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: One idea is have you considered using existing ORM's such as EF or LinqSQL?

Comment: @dreza My application is intensive data read only (to be displayed as tabular data). Hence ORM will be an unwanted performance hit here.

Answer (score 6):

#### Observations

- **You are reinventing the wheel**. Yes, an Object/Relational Mapper such as Entity Framework adds an overhead, but if your queries are `select abc from xyz` I don't see it being an issue.
- Using reflection has an overhead and performance hit, too.
- Projecting `R.report_type_code` into a full-fledged `Report` instance makes no sense. **If you want to select report type codes, return report type codes**, not a bunch of reports without a description.
- **If a command needed a parameter**, would you concatenate it into a `WHERE` statement within the command text, or use an `SqlParameter`? **Would it be the client code's responsibility**? Your code isn't crystal-clear about this.
- A `static` class called `EntityDataMappingHelper` [can be considered a code smell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446376/is-the-word-helper-in-a-class-name-a-code-smell). From [this Programmers.SE answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/111940/68834) (emphasis mine):

  > if a helper method has any external dependency (e.g. a DB) which makes it - thus its callers - **hard to unit test**, it is better to declare it non-static. This allows dependency injection, thus making the method's callers easier to unit test.

---

#### Recommendations

- The `SelectRecords` method doesn't need an *instance*, it needs a *type* - **make your method *generic***, substitute that `Collection<object>` for a `<TEntity>` type parameter with some `where TEntity : class, new()` type constraint.
- You shouldn't be calling your strongly-typed return value `records` - call it `reports` instead, it's less confusing. Or call it `entities` if you prefer a more generic name; a "record" is a low-level thing that a "report" doesn't even know/care about.
- If the database schema is all yours, I think your `Report` entity wants an `Id` property. Just in case there's *eventually* another "entity" that wants to refer to a specific report. Much better than indexing the `ReportName` column.
- Use `List<T>` over the obsolete `ArrayList`:

  > - from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309699/1188513): ArrayList **belongs to the days that C# didn't have generics**. It's deprecated in favor of List. You shouldn't use ArrayList in new code that targets .NET >= 2.0 unless you have to interface with an old API that uses it.

---

#### Alternatives

- Give Entity Framework (Code-First) a try. I'm sure you won't even notice the "performance hit" (given your current code it might actually be a *performance increase*), and **your client code will be much, much simpler**. How about this:

  ```
  IEnumerable<Report> reports;
  IEnumerable<Int16> reportTypeCodes;
  using (var context = new MyEntityFrameworkContext())
  {
      reports = context.Reports.ToList();
      reportTypeCodes = context.Reports
                               .Where(report => report.ReportTypeCode != null)
                               .GroupBy(report => report.ReportTypeCode)
                               .Select(grouping => grouping.Key)
                               .ToList();
  }
  ```
- If you really don't want to use EF, you might actually fall in love with [Dapper.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dapper/info), a micro-ORM - from the SO tag wiki:

  > it focuses on making the materialization as fast as possible, with no overheads from things like identity managers - just "run this query and give me the (typed) data". [...] Quite possibly the fastest materializer available for .NET.